# How to simulate browser file upload with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

guys, first of all thanks for your contributions, I've found great responses here. Yet I've ran into a problem I can't figure out and if someone could provide any help, it would be greatly appreciated.

I'm developing this application in C# that could upload an image from computer to user photoblog. For this I'm usig [pixelpost](http://pixelpost.org/)  platform for photoblogs that is written mainly in PHP.

I've searched here and on other web pages, but the exmples provided there didn't work for me.
Here is what I used in my example: ([Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data)) 
and 
(http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/268661-how-upload-file-via-c-code)
Once it is ready I will make it available for free on the internet and maybe also create a windows mobile version of it, since I'm a fan of pixelpost.

here is the code I've used:

```
        string formUrl = "http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php?x=login";
        string formParams = string.Format("user={0}&password={1}", "user-String", "password-String");
        string cookieHeader;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

        string pageSource;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        string getUrl = "http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php";
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // end first part: login to admin panel

        long length = 0;
        string boundary = "----------------------------" +
        DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php?x=save");
        httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest2.AllowAutoRedirect = false; 
        httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = false;
        httpWebRequest2.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        httpWebRequest2.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);



        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n");


        string formdataTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

        string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, "headline", "image-name");
        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);


        string headerTemplate = "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n";



        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "userfile", "path-to-the-local-file");

        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header);

        memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);


        FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("path-to-the-local-file", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

        int bytesRead = 0;

        while ((bytesRead = fileStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
        {
            memStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

        }

        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);

        fileStream.Close();


        httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

        Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();

        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();


        WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

        Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);


        Console.WriteLine(reader2.ReadToEnd());

        webResponse2.Close();
        httpWebRequest2 = null;
        webResponse2 = null;
```

and also here is the PHP:
(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3149888/index.php)
and 
(http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3149888/new_image.php)

the mandatory fields are *headline* and *userfile* so I can't figure out where the mistake is, as the format sent in right. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the octet-stream sent to the form. 
Maybe it's a stupid mistake I wasn't able to trace, in any case, if you could help me that would mean a lot.

thanks,

Comment: Does the login work, do you get back the cookie?

Comment: Yes, the login works all fine. I get back the cookie and if I display the pageSource string in the console, right before "// end first part: login to admin panel" it contains the HTML code for the admin panel. The for the second request, when I'm sending all the form data and file octet-stream I am able to get back HTML for the "Submit" page with only headline set to 'image-name' and no image is uploaded to the blog. 
So, basically I am not able to upload the image. Normally if something is wrong I should get an error message, instead I get the HTML with headline set.

Comment: Have you tried running fiddler to compare the HTTP traffic when you submit from a browser against that generated by your code? I normally find that helps with getting to the bottom of this sort of isssue.

Comment: Thanks Martin so much, fiddler made the difference. It was actually a Stream format error which fiddler pointed out. I have to admit I've never used it before, so thanks for recommendation.
I'll post the changes below, maybe others are interested too.
best wishes !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So Martin helped me out here and I was able to make the important changes to the code above in order for it to work properly.
The Content-Type had to be changed to image/jpeg. Also I used C# Image type to send image stream.

Also pay attention to the Stream format, as it does not have to contain extra spaces or new lines.

here is the changed part:

```
        string formUrl = "http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php?x=login"; 
        string formParams = string.Format("user={0}&password={1}", "username", "password");
        string cookieHeader;
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(formUrl);
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(formParams);
        req.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
        using (Stream os = req.GetRequestStream())
        {
            os.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        cookieHeader = resp.Headers["Set-Cookie"];

        string pageSource;
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

        string getUrl = "http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php";
        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(getUrl);
        getRequest.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);
        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(getResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            pageSource = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }


        long length = 0;
        string boundary = "----------------------------" +
        DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString("x");

        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/pixelpost/admin/index.php?x=save");
        httpWebRequest2.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary;
        httpWebRequest2.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest2.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        httpWebRequest2.KeepAlive = false;
        httpWebRequest2.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        httpWebRequest2.Headers.Add("Cookie", cookieHeader);

        Stream memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        byte[] boundarybytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("\r\n--" + boundary);


        string headerTemplate = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\"; filename=\"{1}\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n";



        string header = string.Format(headerTemplate, "userfile", "Sunset.jpg");



        byte[] headerbytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(header);

        memStream.Write(headerbytes, 0, headerbytes.Length);


        Image img = null;
        img = Image.FromFile("C:/Documents and Settings/Dorin Cucicov/My Documents/My Pictures/Sunset.jpg", true);
        img.Save(memStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);


        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);


        string formdataTemplate = "\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"{0}\";\r\n\r\n{1}";

        string formitem = string.Format(formdataTemplate, "headline", "Sunset");
        byte[] formitembytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(formitem);
        memStream.Write(formitembytes, 0, formitembytes.Length);

        memStream.Write(boundarybytes, 0, boundarybytes.Length);


        httpWebRequest2.ContentLength = memStream.Length;

        Stream requestStream = httpWebRequest2.GetRequestStream();

        memStream.Position = 0;
        byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[memStream.Length];
        memStream.Read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        memStream.Close();
        requestStream.Write(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.Length);
        requestStream.Close();


        WebResponse webResponse2 = httpWebRequest2.GetResponse();

        Stream stream2 = webResponse2.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(stream2);


        Console.WriteLine(reader2.ReadToEnd());

        webResponse2.Close();
        httpWebRequest2 = null;
        webResponse2 = null;
```

Thank you all again for answering or just reading.